# WCF Rest with PUT method on calling from client side changes to GET method in header request and fails to perform operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf, rest

I have a Restfull WCF service running.
All the operation works perfect and tested.
But when I try to call one of the PUT operation from client side using jquery JSON the header request changes to GET() method though I have mentioned PUT as method.
Tested on fiddler same 405 method not allowed error.
I know as it is a PUT method we can not apply GET but on client side if I use PUT() it automatically changes to GET in header request and fails.
Why it is happening can't get to fix it.Any help or ideas?

My client code for service request is as follows:

```
function UpdateRating(radioValue) {
jQuery.support.cors = true;
var star = (Math.floor(radioValue * 2) / 10).toFixed(2);
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: ServiceURL + "xxx.svc/xml/updatescoreforvideo?vid=" + videoId + "&uid=" + userId + "&score=" + star,
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        alert("you rated : "+ star + "star");//show alert on success //test
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Service call error occured');
    }
});
```

}

My fiddler /firebug error reports :
[image]

Comment: If any clarification is needed i will add more code to the question for better understanding.Thanks

Comment: ok.I got this issue solved.added this feature. crossDomain: true.It worked as expected.Its important to make cross browser compatibility to make the REST service call work .